# Combining 300+ pictures into one banner

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

I need to combine 300+ single pictures (portraits) of equal size in to 1 banner. For example 10x30 pictures within a fixed format (about 50X140 centimeters).

There has to be a faster way than resize and drag and drop every single picture in to my PSD document.

Answer (score 0):

InDesign could be better for this as you can set up a 50x140cm page and fill it with blank frames for your 10x30 pictures. All these frames can be then set up to use an object style which will automatically fit the images proportionally so you don't have to resize each photo by hand.

Then you can import all 300 pictures via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and clicking each frame will place each image. You will have to click 300 times for each frame, but with the proper setup this will be all you need to do.

With all the photos imported you can then generate a print-ready PDF using the built-in press-ready PDF export presets.

InDesign can also import photos automatically via CSV, but this will require some more advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Adobe Output Module (AOM) for Bridge.
If you use CC, I believe you have to install it. If you use CS6, module is already included.

The original purpose of this module is to create contact sheets (or web galleries), but it might serve your needs here.

https://helpx.adobe.com/bridge/using/create-web-galleries-pdfs-adobe.html#create_a_pdf_contact_sheet